# Can't get user presence correctly - Roblox API

Tags: api, roblox

I am developing a Chrome extension that sets your Discord Rich Presence status based on what you're doing on the Roblox website, and I want to detect if the user is playing a game. However, Roblox's [Presence API](https://presence.roblox.com/docs/) doesn't seem to be working correctly.

When I give it a user ID on the API site, it returns the currently played game correctly, but when I run the cURL command it generates it does not return the `universeId`, `gameId`, `rootPlaceId`, `placeId`, or `lastLocation`.

Here's the response generated by the website:

```json
{
  "userPresences": [
    {
      "userPresenceType": 2,
      "lastLocation": "[Leaderboards!] The Rake REMASTERED",
      "placeId": 2413927524,
      "rootPlaceId": 2413927524,
      "gameId": "436735c2-7010-4dd0-83a1-0e3af1510779",
      "universeId": 847722000,
      "userId": 1843923756,
      "lastOnline": "2022-02-28T14:56:06.823Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

cURL command generated by the website:

```sh
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "userIds": [ \ 
     1843923756 \ 
   ] \ 
 }' 'https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/users'
```

and here's what the cURL command returns:

```json
{
    "userPresences": [{
        "userPresenceType": 2,
        "lastLocation": "",
        "placeId": null,
        "rootPlaceId": null,
        "gameId": null,
        "universeId": null,
        "userId": 1843923756,
        "lastOnline": "2022-02-28T14:56:06.823Z"
    }]
}
```

The only solution I can think of is using Roblox's legacy presence API (https://api.roblox.com/Users/1843923756/OnlineStatus) but I can't access it on the Roblox website.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include the **.ROBLOSECURITY** Cookie within your request's header.

This is how it would look like within CURL:

```
curl -X 'POST' 'https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/users' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Cookie: .ROBLOSECURITY=_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|' \
-d '{
    "userIds": [
       373806907
    ]
}'
```