# How do I retrieve a user's Game ID using the Roblox presence API?

Tags: api, roblox, luau

I am asking here since the Roblox Dev Forum does not let me post for some reason. Anyhow, I am trying to make a feature in my game which lets the player join their friend's game through the game itself from a simple search, however, when I make an api request to the API, it only returns what is shown in the screenshot. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHgRy.png)
The API I am can be found here: https://presence.roblox.com/docs/index.html
The URL for the API is https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/users
Clearly, in the Swagger API, one of the things that it's supposed to return is "Game ID" which I believe is the JobID in which the user currently is. Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

I tried to make a normal request, according to the swagger UI page, but what I received was (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHgRy.png), and game ID was nowhere to be found. Moreover, I tried using this fix outlined here, [Can't get user presence correctly - Roblox API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71297109/cant-get-user-presence-correctly-roblox-api), (adding the cookie) and it still returned the same result.